# imread from string instead of file?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is it possible to read encoded image content from a string instead of a file in MATLAB?

Something like this:

```
data_string = '����JFIF``���C......'    
imread(data_string);
```

Comment: why not just use fread ?

Comment: Let's say I have read the file with fread. Now I want to decode it into a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work-around, write the string into a file:

```
 fid = fopen('temp.jpg','wt');
 fprintf(fid, data_string);
 fclose(fid);
```

And then read:

```
 im = imread('temp.jpg');
```